# JWT auth from android apps

Tags: java, android, apache, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am fairly new to Android development and need to make a call to a HTTP server to upload an image. Before doing so, the user logs in with a username and password and a JWT token is returned along with the user id. In the image upload function, I need to provide the token and the id for the server to accept the image after validating the session, and that is where I am running into problems.

I am not sure if the problem lies in the image upload or in the session validation, though from the error messages it seems to be the second case.

The function is the following:

```
public String sendPostMult(String myurl, String token, List<ValuePair> params, Bitmap bm) throws Exception {

    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(myurl);
        post.addHeader("Authorization", "Token token=\"" + token + "\"");
        MultipartEntityBuilder postEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bao);

        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();

        String ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);

        // File file = new File("Your File path on SD card");
        // postEntity.addPart("fileupload", new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg"));
        for (ValuePair param : params) {
            postEntity.addTextBody(param.getValue(), param.getName());
            Log.d(param.getValue(), param.getName());
        }

        postEntity.addTextBody("client_assertion_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer");


        postEntity.addTextBody("client_assertion", token);

        postEntity.addTextBody("picture", ba1);
        // Log.d("YY", getBytesFromBitmap(bm).toString());
        post.setEntity(postEntity.build());

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

        String sResponse = reader.readLine();

        return sResponse;

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

The errors given are the following (please take a look at the last one):

```
11-11 10:51:09.780  11762-12135/team13.foods I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=686) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault﹕ (thUse=686) NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault()

11-11 10:51:09.780  11762-12135/team13.foods I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=686) - KeeperManager﹕ (thUse=686) INITIALIZATION of shared resources

11-11 10:51:09.780  11762-12135/team13.foods I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=686) - AndroidContextProviderImpl﹕ (thUse=686)    currentActivityThread=android.app.ActivityThread@420899a8
11-11 10:51:09.830  11762-12135/team13.foods I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=686) - GbaSupportIndicatorRequestUpdaterDefault﹕ (thUse=686) GbaSupportIndicatorRequestUpdaterAbstract()   userHeaderPredefined=Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

11-11 10:51:09.940  11762-11769/team13.foods I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 11
11-11 10:51:09.940  11762-11769/team13.foods I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 12
11-11 10:51:09.940  11762-11769/team13.foods I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 13
11-11 10:51:09.940  11762-11769/team13.foods I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 14
11-11 10:51:09.950  11762-11769/team13.foods I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 15

11-11 10:51:09.960  11762-12135/team13.foods D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser;.INSTANCE

11-11 10:51:09.960  11762-12135/team13.foods W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1921 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser;

11-11 10:51:09.960  11762-12135/team13.foods D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x001b

11-11 10:51:09.960  11762-12135/team13.foods D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter;.INSTANCE

11-11 10:51:09.960  11762-12135/team13.foods W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1915 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter;

11-11 10:51:09.960  11762-12135/team13.foods D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0015
11-11 10:51:09.970  11762-12135/team13.foods D/name﹕ djt
11-11 10:51:09.970  11762-12135/team13.foods D/description﹕ test
11-11 10:51:09.970  11762-12135/team13.foods D/tags﹕ hft
11-11 10:51:09.970  11762-12135/team13.foods D/id﹕ 545a7b69ed2f9c0200dfc995
11-11 10:51:10.000  11762-12135/team13.foods D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 799K, 16% free 7878K/9336K, paused 27ms, total 27ms

11-11 10:51:10.020  11762-12135/team13.foods I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=686) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault﹕ (thUse=686)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=null

11-11 10:51:10.020  11762-12135/team13.foods I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=686) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault﹕ (thUse=686)    The current context is NOT a context of GBA service.

11-11 10:51:10.020  11762-12135/team13.foods I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=686) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl﹕ (thUse=686) isCurrentProcessRequestedGba()#finished   result=false

11-11 10:51:10.020  11762-12135/team13.foods I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=686) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl﹕ (thUse=686) isCurrentProcessAllowedToUseGba()#started   result=false

11-11 10:51:10.020  11762-12135/team13.foods I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=686) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault﹕ (thUse=686)    The GBA permission wasn't requested for this process.

11-11 10:51:10.020  11762-12135/team13.foods I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=686) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault﹕ (thUse=686) It is impossible to support GBA now (many possible reasons: no Android Context, current client is GBA service, etc.), then it will be just usual HTTP.

11-11 10:51:10.020  11762-12135/team13.foods I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=686) - NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler﹕ (thUse=686)    It isn't GBA flow, redirection responses are not handled.

11-11 10:51:11.280  11762-12135/team13.foods W/DefaultRequestDirector﹕ Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}

11-11 10:51:11.280  11762-12135/team13.foods I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=686) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault﹕ (thUse=686)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=false

11-11 10:51:11.280  11762-11762/team13.foods I/System.out﹕ UnauthorizedError: jwt must be provided
```

So it seems that it is indeed a jwt error. If I remove the

```
post.addHeader("Authorization", "Token token=\"" + token + "\"");
```

line, the error says: Authorization header must be provided.

So my questions are:

1) Is the authorization header correct? Or should it be in another format?

2) How do I pass the JWT? I received the token as a string and I figured that is what I needed to pass. It is true however that when I received the token it contained several fields which I parsed into different strings, the token being one of them. So maybe I should just save the entire thing and send it altogether in the client assertion field? But then should I still send the token only in the authorization header?

3) While a little unrelated, could it be that I am sending the image in the wrong format?

Thank you so much for your time. I really appreciate it!

Comment: In case you are wondering what the JWT looks like: {"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGiOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im9saUBvbGkuY29tIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiIkMmEkMDUkZEVpYmhRUzlNLlMwRW9wTU5XWndrLi5rR1VIMWNFUk9HaW1mMDRYcFpnQWdtSTBBbTFPRk8iLCJfaWQiOiI1NDVhN2I2OWVkMmY5YzAyMDBkZmM5OTUiLCJfX3YiOjB9.voPftTnS4Wfg_S6_87N6DUpBxCcu9S_dyJpUj_rsxlk","id":"545a7b69ed2f9c0200dfc995"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the JWT your problem is right there. It is not a JWT-token.

A JWT consists of three parts: `<header>.<claims/payload>.<signature>`. Yours only contain `<payload>.<signature>`. I suspect you have a JWS (JSON Web Signature) and not a JWT (JSON Web Token).

You can read about the format in the specs: http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#ExampleJWT

If you need to troubleshoot tokens this is a helpful tool: http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/mobile/tool_jwt.html

Also, sending the password in a claim like you do seems like a backwards thing to do, even if it is encrypted. JWT is instead of sending passwords to each service. Services trust the content by validating the signature.